# Oracle Read only access to specific user

Tags: oracle

I have a schema and many users in it. For development I would like to give permission to the user to only read the tables and not having permission to manipulate database. Are there any commands to set access rights for a particular user to read only?

Comment: Which database do you use? MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: No, you do _not_ have "a schema and many users in it.".  Users are not _in_ schemas.  Users _own_ their own schema.  User = owner = schema.  Now, to your question - in oracle everything is forbidden unless _specifically_ granted.  If you want a given user to have read-only access to another user's (schema's) table, then don't GRANT that user anything other than SELECT ON OTHER_USER.TABLE_NAME.  My comments are directed to oracle.  Since you've tagged 2 different rdbms products we don't know which one you are really asking about.

Comment: @Littlefoot Oracle Database

Comment: @jps Not Excatly brother

Comment: @Tech_Delhi: you tagged it mysql (and also C#), so don't be surprised, when the answer doesn't fit your need. The right answer for Oracle should be as easy to find as the one for mysql.

Comment: @Tech_Delhi If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in the given answers, don't hesitate to ask the author.

Comment: @Tech_Delhi Did you read my comment above? Seems you have never accepted any answer to any of your questions. Please read the above linked help page.

Answer (score 1):

As Ed commented, you aren't allowed to do anything unless granted. For read-only users, you'd grant only the `SELECT` privilege on your tables. If you have only a few of them, do it manually. Otherwise, create a procedure which will do it for you. Here's an example.

These are my tables:

```
SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
BONUS                          TABLE
DEPT                           TABLE
EMP                            TABLE
LINKS                          TABLE
SALGRADE                       TABLE
```

A procedure which loops through all tables in my schema and grants `SELECT` to user passed as a parameter:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_grant_ro(par_user in varchar2) is
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_name from user_tables
  5                  order by table_name
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      l_str := 'grant select on ' || cur_r.table_name ||
  9               ' to ' || dbms_assert.schema_name(par_user);
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 11      execute immediate(l_str);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec p_grant_ro('MIKE');
grant select on BONUS to MIKE
grant select on DEPT to MIKE
grant select on EMP to MIKE
grant select on LINKS to MIKE
grant select on SALGRADE to MIKE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you wonder what's the purpose of `dbms_assert` function's call: preventing possible SQL injection. Function takes care that parameter is an existing schema name.

```
SQL> exec p_grant_ro('TECH_DELHI');
BEGIN p_grant_ro('TECH_DELHI'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44001: invalid schema
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 266
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_GRANT_RO", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure this in e.g. MYSQL Workbench.
I think there is also a way to link this to an Apex user.